# Find especific links in files

Tags: python

I have some txt files with lots of urls like these:

```
www.example.com/spare_parts/M2541.htm
www.example.com/spare_parts/M3511.htm
www.example.com/spare_parts/C6501.htm
www.example.com/spare_parts/M2800.htm
www.example.com/custom_parts/M1808.htm
www.example.com/custom_parts/R2202.htm
```

What I want is a sorted list of links. I have managed to load my txt files and read by line in python, but I can´t sort it because all examples I found was looking for words, and in this case I want the links for all spare parts that starting with M. Can someone help me?

```
for line in text:
    if 'spare_parts' in line:
        print texto2(line)
    else:
        print texto3(line)
```

Comment: can you show us what you have done already?

Comment: Are you trying to *sort* or *filter*?

Comment: I was trying it by searching words (spare_parts), but it doesnt show any results. i will post my code

Comment: @RTD your title is slightly contradicting what you're asking for. Do you want list of spareparts which start with `M` or hyperlinks for list of parts starting with `M`

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear, i want urls of that parts. i will now start to get those files. exM1808.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parts=[]
FirstLetter='M'
fp=open('textfile.txt')
for line in fp:
    if 'spare_parts' in line:
        part =line.rstrip().split('/')[-1].strip('.htm')
        if part.startswith(FirstLetter):
            parts.append(part)

print sorted(parts)
```

output:
`['M2541','M2800','M3511']`

Comment: `.readlines()` might be a trouble if the file is really big. `for line in file_obj` would work better.

Comment: Thanks Ashoka, acutally i need the full line, i will grab this htm from the web. but this will also be useful afterwards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a filter:

```
urlList = [
    "www.example.com/spare_parts/M2541.htm",
    "www.example.com/spare_parts/M3511.htm",
    "www.example.com/spare_parts/C6501.htm",
    "www.example.com/spare_parts/M2800.htm",
    "www.example.com/custom_parts/M1808.htm",
    "www.example.com/custom_parts/R2202.htm"
]
sparePartsStartingWithMList = [line for line in urlList if ("/spare_parts/M" in line)]
```

The important line is the last line, it's a list comprehension that returns a list containing all strings that have "/spare_parts/M" in them. The equivalent loop would be this:

```
sparePartsStartingWithMList = []

for line in urlList:
    if ("/spare_parts/M" in line:
        sparePartsStartingWithMList.append(line)
```

Due to the nature of your URLs, all spare parts are under the directory `/spare_parts` and all your spare parts have their identifications as the filename. So you can just search for the relevant part of the path, that is the folder followed by a directory separator (`/`) then the first letter of the part identification.

Value of `sparePartsStartingWithMList`:

```
sparePartsStartingWithMList = [
    "www.example.com/spare_parts/M2541.htm",
    "www.example.com/spare_parts/M3511.htm",
    "www.example.com/spare_parts/M2800.htm"
]
```

Comment: Thanks Kroltan it will help also when i reach next steps